# Como enviar valores do FORM para o Controller no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sou novo no ASP.NET e estou criando uma aplicação MVC. Tenho, no meu controller um método que funciona da seguinte forma:

```
 public ActionResult ShowClients(string proc)
    {
        --(proc)EXECUTA ALGUMA LOGICA AQUI
       return View();

    }
```

A lógica deste método já foi testada e está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema é que preciso passar esta string "proc" para este controller através de um form que fica na view (no caso seria o parâmetro que o usuário digitaria).
Então, quando o usuário preenchesse o textbox e clicasse no botão submit o método seria chamado com o que estivesse escrito no textbox.
Com o código abaixo, fui capaz de fazer o envio do parâmetro para o método mas o problema é que além de o @url.Action ser um método GET, eu também não consigo inserir variáveis nele (pelo menos não que eu saiba):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="NICK" name="proc" placeholder="Digite Nome ou CPF">
    <input type="submit" onclick="parent.location='@Url.Action("ShowClients", "Clientes", new { proc = "SAUL DOM" })';return false;" value="Pesquisar" >
</form>
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isto?

Comment: Você pode fazer o envio desses dados através de Razor ou JS Ajax, quanto a colocar parametros para métodos Get, você pode colocar sim, se não pudesse nunca poderíamos fazer a consulta para retornar somente uma entidade por ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um submit simples já basta para esse cenário. Recomendo utilizar o *html helper* `BeginForm` do MVC para geração do formulário:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ShowClients"))
{
    <input type="text" id="proc" name="proc" placeholder="Digite Nome ou CPF">
    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" >
}
```

Alterando o código da sua view para o exemplo acima já é o suficiente para que a action `ShowClients` receba a valor esperado.

Observe que o comportamento da `tag input` do tipo `submit` é fazer o `post` do formulário em que ela está inserida por padrão.

O ASP.NET MVC, por convenção, recebe os valores dos campos de um formulário desde que os parâmetros da `action` que recebe o `post` tenham os mesmos nomes dos elementos na tela.

O *html helper* `BeginForm` aceita o nome da action a receber o submit do formulário como um dos seus parâmetros.

Obs: Você deve utilizar essa forma somente se a página foi exibida através da mesma controller à qual você deve enviar os dados.

Comment: não é melhor usar:
@using (Html.BeginForm("SuaActionX", "SeuControllerX", FormMethod.Get))
{
    // ...
} ?

Comment: Ele precisaria usar dessa forma no caso de estar fazendo o post para uma action de uma controller diferente da que carregou o formulário. E também se ele quisesse enviar o formulário com get ao invés de post, o que não é o cenário ideal.

Comment: discordo, pois assumir que o usuário está carregando essa página através da mesma controller e não mencionar isso na resposta pode levar o usuário a usar seu método de Get de uma maneira errada, já da forma que mencionei, o usuário poderia usar sem restrição.

Comment: Verdade, vou editar a minha resposta para aumentar a clareza da implementação.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Marcell, era isto mesmo que eu precisava, bastou referenciar a action e o controller correto e tudo deu certinho! Não tenho palavras para agradecer!!!

Comment: @NugoSunes por favor marque a resposta dele como correta então, assim os próximos usuários com a mesma dúvida já vão ir pra resposta dele ;) +1